# Struggling with waffle - mock not initialized

Tags: waffle, mock

I've got problem with mocking method call. Below is my solidity code and test.
I would like to pass mock into withdraw method and check if transfer function was called. But instead I am getting error "Mock on the method is not initialized". Any clue? :)

```
  function withdraw(IERC20 token, uint256 amount) external onlyOwner {
        token.transfer(msg.sender, amount);
    }
```

```
describe('LoanManager', () => {
  const [owner, notOwner] = new MockProvider().getWallets();
  let loanManager;
  
beforeEach(async () => {
    loanManager = await deployContract(owner, LoanManager);
  });
    
it('Owner should be able to withdraw', async () => {
        let token = await deployMockContract(owner, IERC20.abi);
        const amount = 5;
        token.mock.transfer.withArgs(owner.address, amount).returns(true);
        loanManager.withdraw(token.address, amount);
        await expect('transfer').to.be.calledOnContract(token);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is most likely because you didn't `await` when mocking the function.

```
token.mock.transfer.withArgs(...)
```

should be

```
await token.mock.transfer.withArgs(...)
```

Hope it helps.